# Vibrate using JavaScript on specific amount when counter hits?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with one thing, can I make use phone vibrate when they reach a specific number on the list like 10 on the counter, you guys will understand it much better when you will gonna run the code. I know we can make the phone vibrate using javascript but I can't find a way to put it into this code need help with this. **A simple Quote is When use reach to 10 in counter phone should vibrate.** Please do help

```js
var clicks = 0;

// extracted this for DRYness
function displayClicks() {
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}

function onSelect() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  // simply reset the clicks and rerender them
  clicks = 0;
  displayClicks();
};


function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  displayClicks();
};

//function mycount() {
//  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
//  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
//}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>script</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Select a AWRAD from the list.</p>

  <select id="mySelect" onchange="onSelect()">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Al-ASaS">الاساس</option>
    <option value="IztikFar">استغفار</option>
  </select>

  <p>Your Selected Awrad will be shown here.</p>

  <!--Custom Div-->

  <div style="width: 200px;height: 100px;border: 2px green solid;border-radius: 5px;" id="div-j">

    <h4 id="demo" style="text-align: center;"></h4>
    <p id="clicks" style="text-align: center;"></p>


  </div>


  <!--Custom Div Ends-->


  <br>
  <!--<p id="clicks"></p><br>-->



  <img src="https://mb.burhaniya.pk/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/counter.png" onClick="onClick()" width="70" height="70" />
  <!--<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>-->
  
  </body>
```

Comment: *"I know we can make the phone vibrate using javascript"* - You mean for example with the [vibration API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API)?  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: can you just help me i just want phone to vibrate when it hits 10's count on the counter thats it

Comment: You should learn more about conditional and [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) in Javascript.

Comment: can you please just help me like you can the div with the id of "clicks" I just want when it has the value of 10 the vibration API should trigger. i am just asking that why is not body asking me properly

Comment: @vcyw: Please take some time to start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.  You are asking this community to do all of your work for you.  Even if it's not difficult to do, it's still an imposition to ask while showing no effort whatsoever on your part.  There are websites where you can hire a programmer to work for you, but this is not one of them.  It's possible someone may volunteer to do your work for you, but it's unlikely.  Instead, you are encouraged to at least *try*.  When you try, if you encounter a specific problem, we can help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to [Vibration_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API) and read the documentation.
From what I've understood from your question, you might want to change your onClick() function implementation to this

```
function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  if(clicks === 10) 
       window.navigator.vibrate(2000); // vibrate for 2 seconds

  displayClicks();
};
```